# Concatenar dos variables obtenidas por el metodo getElementByID

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Necesito concatenar dos objetos obtenidos por el metodo mencionado anteriormente

```
 var textApellido   = document.getElementById('textApellido');
 var textNombre     = document.getElementById('textNombre'); 
 var resultado = textNombre + textApellido;
```

Obteniendo como resulado

> Cannot read property **'toString'** of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso te pasa por que estas capturando el elemento mas no su valor, para capturar el valor debes hacer lo siguiente:

**1. Si es un elemento de formulario**

```
var textApellido   = document.getElementById('textApellido').value;
var textNombre     = document.getElementById('textNombre').value;
```

**2. Si es un div o cualquier otro elemento que no sea de formulario**

```
var textApellido   = document.getElementById('textApellido').innerHTML;
var textNombre     = document.getElementById('textNombre').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Si, es verdad, pensé que realmente era por algun error mío, pero realmente estoy usando un Framework de una Impresora Dymo450 y no me permite relacionar los elementos de esa manera, a no ser que la variable esté sola: *var textInput      = textNombre;*

Comment: Aunque se concatene elementos, no es el origen del error porque en ese caso, el intérprete usaría la representación en string del elemento por medio del método `toString`, lo cual daría como resultado: `[object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement]`.